# Ant task for retrieving revision's author

Tags: svn, ant

I have the following lines in my *build.xml* file:

```
<target name="svn.load.properties" description="Load svn revision properties">
        <loadfile property="svn.info.author" srcFile=".svn/entries" failonerror="true">
            <filterchain>
                <headfilter lines="12"/>
                <tailfilter lines="1"/>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <filetokenizer/>
                    <replaceregex pattern="(.*)([\r\n].*)*" flags="s" replace="\1"/>
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadfile>
    </target>
```

But the value of the `"svn.info.author"` property eventually occurs to be "12" (and accordingly *.svn/entries* file contains only one value - "12"). At the same time the name of revision's author in the svn commit log is displayed correctly (as login from my svn credentials). Can I change this file (*.svn/entries*) to retrieve name of revision's author and, if yes, then how (with which rules), or how can I retrieve name of revision's author in another way?

As far as I understand it, the problem is in my *.svn/entries* file. So why does not this file contain anything except "12"?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the official svn ant task available [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html).

Donwload the last [release](http://subclipse.tigris.org/files/documents/906/43359/svnant-1.2.1.zip).

Unzip.

In the doc folder, open the file "svn.html" in your browser.

Look at the "info" task.

It says : The task sets the following properties (prefix applied accordingly): author.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool, like subWCRev, to change a .properties file in your project, and after, read it. Like, (https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html)

Let's imagine you have a project with a build_info_template.properties
with these entries:

```
build.major.number=01  
build.minor.number=00  
build.revision.number=00  
build.svn.revision.number=$WCREV$  
build.svn.revision.date=$WCNOWUTC$
```

After on your Ant script you have to run SubWCRev:

```
<target name="update_properties">
    <!-- update properties file with subWCRev(Tortoise)-->
    <exec executable="cmd">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="SubWCRev" />
        <!--Project folder-->
        <arg value="C:\Desenv\workspaceServer\project" />
        <!--Template file-->
        <arg value="C:\Desenv\workspaceServer\project\Ant\build_info_template.properties" />
        <!--Target file-->
        <arg value="C:\Desenv\workspaceServer\project\Ant\build_info.properties" />
        <!--Suppress outline-->
        <arg value="-q" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

After run target update_properties you read properties file generated(not template) with:

```
<property file="build_info.properties" />
<property name="svn.build.number" value="${build.svn.revision.number}" />
```

And voilá, just use your svn.build.number variable.